# Access members of one class from another class

Tags: java

The code:

```
import java.util.*;
/*
TicTac Game
__X_|__O_|__X_
__O_|__X_|__O_
  X |  O |  X
*/
public class TicTac{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Welcome.greet();
    Game start = new Game();
    start.inputName();
    Welcome.greetPlayer();
    start.show();
  }
}
class Welcome{
  public static void greet(){
    System.out.println("\tTicTac Game By Abhi:");
    System.out.println("\t  __X_|__O_|__X_");
    System.out.println("\t  __O_|__X_|__O_");
    System.out.println("\t    X |  O |  X");
  }
  public static void greetPlayer(){
    Game call = new Game();
    System.out.println("Welcome " + " " + call.x + " and " + call.y + "\n" + "Have Fun!");
  }
}
class Game{
  public String x,y;
  public void inputName(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name Player 1:");
    String Player1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your name Player 2:");
    String Player2 = input.nextLine();
    x = Player1;
    y = Player2;
  }
  public void show(){
    System.out.println("Hi " + " " + x + " and " + y);
  }
}
```

When I try to call Welcome.greetPlayer() it gives a null value both times.
But whenever try to call start.show it give me values of x and y.
I want to access String x and y in welcome class.

Comment: Why are you creating two instances of Game? call = new Game() in Welcome.greetPlayer() is not necessary. You could also move the method in Game class.

Comment: One way to that is that `start.inputName();` method to return some values which you can then pass it into `Welcome.greetPlayer();` as parameters. You could create a `Player` object and then use `Map<String, Player>` as return type from `start.inputName();` and lastly you can pass it into `Welcome.greetPlayer(playersMap);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using two different `Game` objects. The first is created in your `main()` method, the second in the `greetPlayer()` method. You are initializing the player names only for the object in the `main()` method. They are never initialized in the second object.

I assume you want to use only one `Game` object. One solution would be to pass the `Game` object to the `greetPlayer()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Welcome.greet();
    Game start = new Game();
    start.inputName();
    Welcome.greetPlayer(start);
    start.show();
}
```

```
public static void greetPlayer(Game call){
    System.out.println("Welcome " + " " + call.x + " and " + call.y + "\n" + "Have Fun!");
}
```

Another option would be to pass the names directly to the `greetPlayer()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Welcome.greet();
    Game start = new Game();
    start.inputName();
    Welcome.greetPlayer(start.x, start.y);
    start.show();
}
```

```
public static void greetPlayer(String player1, String player2){
    System.out.println("Welcome " + " " + player1 + " and " + player2 + "\n" + "Have Fun!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `Game call = new Game();` in `greetPlayer()`

You have a new instance of Game so your are losing the `x` and `y` of your input.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating object of the `Game()` in two places.

In main():

```
Game start = new Game();
```

And in `greetPlayer()`:

```
Game call = new Game();
```

You can try to merge two classes, so you have players introduction, getting names and rest of the game in one class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game start = new Game();
        Game.greet();
        start.inputName();
        start.show();
    }
}

class Game {
    public String x, y;

    public void inputName() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name Player 1:");
        String player1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your name Player 2:");
        String player2 = input.nextLine();

        x = player1;
        y = player2;
    }

    public static void greet() {
        System.out.println("\tTicTac Game By Abhi:");
        System.out.println("\t  __X_|__O_|__X_");
        System.out.println("\t  __O_|__X_|__O_");
        System.out.println("\t    X |  O |  X");
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.printf("Hi %s and %s", x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `start` instance of your Game class passed into the call to the greetPlayer function as a parameter. Try something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTac{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Welcome.greet();
    Game start = new Game();
    start.inputName();
    Welcome.greetPlayer(start);
    start.show();
  }
)
class Welcome{
  public static void greetPlayer(Game call){
    System.out.println("Welcome " + " " + call.x + " and " + call.y + "\n" + "Have Fun!");
  }
}
```